# How to determine which character is most evenly distributed in php

Tags: php, arrays, math, distribution

I am trying to figure out which character is most evenly distributed within a file. So for each character I am analyzing, I have an array that looks like the following...

```
[
    [10.5, 0, 0, 25.1, 0, 10.0, 0, 12.5, 12.5, 0],
    [2.66, 2.33, 0, 0, 0, 10.0, 0, 10.0, 12.5, 0.5],
    ... and so on ...
]
```

Each row represents a line of text cut into tenths. Each value represents the *percentage* of the section that is taken up by the character in question.

With me so far? Now I am trying to figure out how to come up with a metric to compare these characters' distribution. Like, using this, which character has the most even distribution across each line? I have a table like this for each character. If I could use this table to come up with a metric for each character I could then simply compare the metric to determine the most evenly distributed character. This problem is tough to even describe, let alone solve. Hopefully this makes sense. Even just a point in the right direction would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some thorough discussion about the best solution, and why storing the delimiter is not an option (see comments for both), my idea is as follows:

1. Split the string on a proposed delimiter (such as comma, slash, etc.)
2. Join the multiple lines into one array, for ease of calculation
3. Calculate the standard deviation of the length of the elements of said array
4. The lowest standard deviation is the most delimeter

Comment: And I must say... your idea worked beautifully. I am so stoked. This is a third of the amount of lines of my non-working solution. I could kiss you right now man. Thanks again!!

Comment: Although I did end up going with the average deviation rather than total. But I'm happy. It gets the answer right over 90% of the time and that's fine by me. Thanks!